# Function Passed in Object Attribute Not Recognised as Function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am passing an `options` object into my `SelectableUploadField` component. One of the attributes of the items in the `options` object array is `setter`, which is a function.

When I try to call the `setter` function in the component, I get an error in the console saying `options.setter is not a function` and I'm not sure why.

**Parent Component** (that passes the props)

```
export default function ParentComponent() {
    const [documents, setDocuments] = useState({})

    function insertDocument(name, document) {
        setDocuments(prevState => ({
            ...prevState,
            [name]: document
        }))
    }

    return(
        <SelectableUploadField 
            options={[
                {
                    typeId: 'typeId1',
                    shortLabel: 'label1', 
                    title: 'title1', 
                    description: 'description 2', 
                    setter: insertDocument
                },
                {
                    typeId: 'typeId2',
                    shortLabel: 'label2', 
                    title: 'title2', 
                    description: 'description2', 
                    setter: insertDocument
                }
            ]}
            organisation={organisation}
        />
    )
}
```

**Child Component** (that throws the error)

```
function SelectableUploadField({ options }) {
    function handleClick() {
        options[0].setter(options.typeId, { name: 'myDocument', type: 'pdf' })
    }

    return(
        <button onClick={handleClick}>Click me</button>
    )
}
```

Why am I getting the error when `options[index].setter` is clearly a function?

Comment: Hard to say. At least `options.typeId` should throw an error. What happens when you pass `insertDocument` as a separate prop? Makes more sense like that, IMO.

Comment: You're right. Storing `setter` makes more sense. Moving it as a separate prop makes the error disappear - thanks. If you don't mind, I'll keep this open though because I'd like to get down to the reason why the first approach didn't work.